# Raspberry Pi no signal to hdmi

Tags: boot, hdmi, video, signal

This is the first time I've tried to use a raspberry pi, I bought a CannaKit that came preloaded with NOOBS. When I attempt to boot with the HDMI my screen says no signal, the HDMI output is correct, I've verfifyed that the cord works. When I search online forms want me to change a config file from the SD card, I've searched all the folders and there is no config file; or they tell you type something in, i have no video output so I cant see if i'm typing or anything. Does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I *just* voted to close this very question on SO, and stated this: "I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not programming related, and is better suited for the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange. If you ask there, include in your question which LEDs on the Pi light up, and when." ...please update your question with what your LEDs are doing, and when!

Comment: All I see is a steady red light

Comment: Edit and update your question with that *very* important piece of information! That is the exact information that will lead you to an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Given the information in the comments (the red LED staying on solid) means that the SD card does not have a valid boot partition (ie. Operating System) on it.

A solid red LED indicates that the Pi is ok, but it can't start up.

You need to re-flash the SD card, put it back into the Pi, and power it up.

Installation instructions can be found [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md) for both NOOBS and Raspian OS builds. You'll need to read through all of the information, including the link that directs you to the Operating System you're running on your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Check the board itself, I tried many of times to get the thing booted up but got 'No signal' every time. Came to the conclusion it was a faulty board. On the board where it says HDMI there is l4,l5,l6,l7 chips or whatever they are, I was missing l7[image]